# Apache ignite cluster replication to another cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, ignite, gridgain

I have a use-case where I have to **replicate Apache Ignite data(persistent + non-persistent) from one cluster(hosted on AWS) to another(hosted on GCP)** and eventually shut down the original cluster.

I have come across GridGain. They have [DataCenter replication](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication/introduction) and [Kafka Connect integration](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/integrations/kafka/kc-ex-replication) methods available. Though this looks promising, it is available in enterprise edition.

I am more inclined towards using open-source. So, Need guidance if there's a good way of doing this replication. Please point me to the resources.

Also, guide on which replication method of Gridgain should be considered.

Comment: What is the use case: replicating updates from one datacenter to another in real time, or just making backups from time to time?

Comment: @AndreiAleksandrov, the use-case is replicating everything from one data center to another in real-time

Comment: Then you should use something like JTA manager between two clusters - https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/jta/package-summary.html or using Kafka integration for Ignite - https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/streaming/kafka-streamer. However, GridGain replication is much easier to use - https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication/configuring-replication.

Comment: @AndreiAleksandrov, Is there any example how to use JTA manager between 2 clusters? Or documentation?

Comment: @vs777 You can try to use Atomikos transaction manager as here - https://github.com/wangguofeng1923/ignite-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wangguofeng1923/ignite/examples/grid/TransactionsDemo.java